# Merging two data frames in R results in no join for certain observations

Tags: r, merge, left-join

I have two `data.frame` that I'm trying to merge using three key variables. This really should be a left outer join resulting in 1633 observations.

I've run it using `merge()` and `data.table()` and haven't had success with either. I've been running this as a full outer join, just to see where issues are occurring.

The first `data.frame` has the 1633 observations with 12 variables, and the second has 46800 observations with 7 variables. I am merging on "Date", "State", and "County". The issue that keeps coming up is for date 2015-12-01 for Anchorage, Alaska. I have two IDs from the first `data.frame` that won't merge with the data from the second `data.frame`.

I've tried all forms of the `merge(file1, file2, by=c("Date", "State", "County"), all=TRUE)`, alternating the "all" argument. I've kept it this way because it's the easiest way to see what's not matching up.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

The below is the code, looking at just the Alaska data:

```
dput(file1)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16770, 16738, 17100, 16738, 
16770, 17100), class = "Date"), ID = c(93L, 228L, 1109L, 1218L, 
1267L, 1736L), State = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Alabama", 
"Alaska", "Arizona", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", 
"District Of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Illinois", 
"Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", 
"Mississippi", "Missouri", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Mexico", 
"New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", 
"Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "Tennessee", 
"Texas", "Utah", "Virginia", "Washington"), class = "factor"), 
County = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Anchorage", 
"Anne Arundel", "Arapahoe", "Arlington", "Bay", "Beaufort", 
"Bell", "Bernalillo", "Bexar", "Bossier", "Brevard", "Camden", 
"Charles", "Chatham", "Chattahoochee", "Chesapeake", "Christian", 
"Clark", "Comanche", "Craven", "Cumberland", "Davis", "District Of Columbia", 
"Duval", "El Paso", "Escambia", "Fairfax", "Frederick", "Geary", 
"Greene", "Hampton City", "Hardin", "Harrison", "Hillsborough", 
"Hinds", "Honolulu", "Houston", "Island", "Jefferson", "Kings", 
"Kitsap", "Kleberg", "Lake", "Lakewood", "Liberty", "Madison", 
"Mary's", "Middlesex", "Monroe", "Monterey", "Montgomery", 
"New London", "Newport", "Newport News", "Norfolk City", 
"Nueces", "Okaloosa", "Onslow", "Orange", "Otero", "Peoria", 
"Pierce", "Pima", "Portsmouth", "Prince George's", "Prince William", 
"Pulaski", "Richmond", "San Bernadino", "San Diego", "Santa Barbra", 
"Santa Rosa", "Sarpy", "Shelby", "Snohomish", "Solano", "Stafford", 
"Tarrant", "Tom Green", "Val Verde", "Ventura", "Vernon", 
"Virginia Beach City", "Ward", "Yuba", "Yuma"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
ID = c(93L, 228L, 1109L, 1218L, 1267L, 1736L), .rows = list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

```
dput(file2)
    structure(list(Date = structure(c(16436, 16437, 16438, 16439, 
    16440, 16441, 16442, 16443, 16444, 16445, 16446, 16447, 16448, 
    16449, 16450, 16451, 16452, 16453, 16454, 16455, 16456, 16457, 
    16458, 16459, 16460, 16461, 16462, 16463, 16464, 16465, 16466, 
16467, 16468, 16469, 16470, 16471, 16472, 16473, 16474, 16475, 
16476, 16477, 16478, 16479, 16480, 16481, 16482, 16483, 16484, 
16485, 16486, 16487, 16488, 16489, 16490, 16491, 16492, 16493, 
16494, 16495, 16496, 16497, 16498, 16499, 16500, 16501, 16502, 
16503, 16504, 16505, 16506, 16507, 16508, 16509, 16510, 16511, 
16512, 16513, 16514, 16515, 16516, 16517, 16518, 16519, 16520, 
16521, 16522, 16523, 16524, 16525, 16526, 16527, 16528, 16529, 
16530, 16531, 16532, 16533, 16534, 16535, 16536, 16537, 16538, 
16539, 16540, 16541, 16542, 16543, 16544, 16545, 16546, 16547, 
16548, 16549, 16550, 16551, 16552, 16553, 16554, 16555, 16556, 
16557, 16558, 16559, 16560, 16561, 16562, 16563, 16564, 16565, 
16566, 16567, 16568, 16569, 16570, 16571, 16572, 16573, 16574, 
16575, 16576, 16577, 16578, 16579, 16580, 16581, 16582, 16583, 
16584, 16587, 16588, 16589, 16590, 16591, 16592, 16593, 16594, 
16595, 16596, 16597, 16598, 16599, 16600, 16601, 16602, 16603, 
16604, 16605, 16606, 16607, 16608, 16609, 16610, 16611, 16612, 
16613, 16614, 16615, 16616, 16617, 16618, 16619, 16620, 16621, 
16622, 16623, 16624, 16625, 16626, 16627, 16628, 16629, 16630, 
16631, 16632, 16633, 16634, 16635, 16636, 16637, 16638, 16639, 
16640, 16641, 16642, 16643, 16644, 16645, 16646, 16647, 16648, 
16649, 16650, 16651, 16652, 16653, 16654, 16655, 16656, 16657, 
16658, 16659, 16660, 16661, 16662, 16663, 16664, 16665, 16666, 
16667, 16668, 16669, 16670, 16671, 16672, 16673, 16674, 16675, 
16676, 16677, 16678, 16679, 16680, 16681, 16682, 16683, 16684, 
16685, 16686, 16687, 16688, 16689, 16690, 16691, 16692, 16693, 
16694, 16695, 16696, 16697, 16698, 16699, 16700, 16701, 16702, 
16703, 16704, 16705, 16706, 16707, 16708, 16709, 16710, 16711, 
16712, 16713, 16714, 16715, 16716, 16717, 16718, 16719, 16720, 
16721, 16722, 16723, 16724, 16725, 16726, 16727, 16728, 16729, 
16730, 16731, 16732, 16733, 16734, 16735, 16736, 16737, 16738, 
16739, 16740, 16741, 16742, 16743, 16744, 16745, 16746, 16747, 
16748, 16749, 16750, 16751, 16752, 16753, 16754, 16755, 16756, 
16757, 16758, 16759, 16760, 16761, 16762, 16763, 16764, 16765, 
16766, 16767, 16768, 16769, 16770, 16771, 16772, 16773, 16774, 
16775, 16776, 16777, 16778, 16779, 16780, 16781, 16782, 16783, 
16784, 16785, 16786, 16787, 16788, 16789, 16790, 16791, 16792, 
16793, 16794, 16795, 16796, 16797, 16798, 16799), class = "Date"), 
    State = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", 
    "Arizona", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "District Of Columbia", 
    "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Illinois", "Kentucky", "Maryland", 
    "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Mexico", 
    "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", 
    "Pennsylvania", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Virginia", 
    "Washington", "Louisiana"), class = "factor"), County = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("Anchorage ", "Anne Arundel", "Arapahoe", 
    "Arlington", "Bell", "Bernalillo", "Bexar", "Brevard", "Charles", 
    "Chatham", "Christian", "Clark", "Comanche", "Cumberland", 
    "Davis", "District of Columbia", "Duval", "El Paso", "Escambia", 
    "Fairfax", "Frederick", "Greene", "Hampton City", "Hardin", 
    "Harrison", "Hillsborough", "Hinds", "Honolulu", "Houston", 
    "Kings", "Kitsap", "Madison", "Monterey", "Montgomery", "New London", 
    "Norfolk City", "Nueces", "Orange", "Peoria", "Pierce", "Pima", 
    "Richmond", "San Bernardino", "San Diego", "Santa Barbara", 
    "Sarpy", "Shelby", "Snohomish", "Solano", "Tarrant", "Ventura", 
    "Virginia Beach City", "Ward", "Yuma", "Bossier", "Okaloosa", 
    "Prince George's"), class = "factor"), AQI_25 = c(27, 40.5, 
    54, 70.5, 65.5, 64, 47.5, 29, 40, 60.5, 60, 36.5, 26, 21.5, 
    26, 28, 32, 31, 30, 30, 47, 26.5, 6.5, 6, 48.5, 31.5, 27, 
    45.5, 45.5, 38, 51, 47, NA, NA, 70, 41.5, 12, 58.5, 38.5, 
    29, 26, 36, 22, 34.5, 38.5, 27, 7.5, 11.5, 29, 46.5, 37, 
    14.5, 27.5, 15.5, 26, 26.5, 46, 45, 40, 38.5, 31, 21.5, 26.5, 
    21.5, 22.5, 11.5, 9.5, 16.5, 15, 27.5, 23.5, 17, 22, 15, 
    13, 22.5, 33.5, 28.5, 31.5, 40.5, 28, 35.5, 39, 25.5, 32.5, 
    28.5, 29.5, 26.5, 24.5, 19.5, 16, 18.5, 17, 20.5, 15.5, 8.5, 
    4, 6, 7, 16, 21.5, 16.5, 7.5, 16, 13.5, 10.5, 9, 5.5, 5, 
    7, 10, 14.5, 24.5, 24.5, 23.5, 20, 15, 15.5, 9, 13.5, 17, 
    16, 15, 14, 17.5, 19.5, 14, 12.5, 12, 9, 12.5, 15.5, 18, 
    23, 22, 14, 16.5, 18, 11.5, 20.5, 17.5, 23, 18, 21.5, 14, 
    16, 18, 31.5, NA, NA, 29.5, 19.5, 21.5, 19.5, 23, 24, 28, 
    20, 20.5, 24, 31, 30, 39.5, 61.5, 72, 59.5, 60.5, 57, 51.5, 
    47.5, 40, 44, 49, 41.5, 34, 32.5, 25.5, 27, 26.5, 17.5, 25, 
    49, 32.5, 35.5, 29.5, 20, 19, 19.5, 13, 15, 12.5, 12.5, 9.5, 
    6, 11, 13, 10, 15, 14.5, 29.5, 38.5, 18.5, 19, 24.5, 11, 
    12.5, 15.5, 18, 16.5, 18, 21.5, 32, 34, 32, 24.5, 19, 39, 
    30.5, 25, 8, 11, 9, 16, 23, 26, 24.5, 17.5, 18, 8.5, 14.5, 
    17.5, 16.5, 4, 11, 17, 19.5, 10, 13.5, 10, 6, 6.5, 10, 16, 
    18, 10, 16.5, 25.5, 24.5, 19.5, 14.5, 15, 18, 15, 10.5, 8.5, 
    21.5, 9.5, 9, 8.5, 18.5, 23, 26.5, 10, 13, 15, 14.5, 5, 3, 
    13, 6.5, 10.5, 29.5, 15.5, 10.5, 12, 11.5, 14.5, 16.5, 27, 
    19, 22, 19.5, 21, 27.5, 18.5, 21.5, 20, 11.5, 17, 20, 18, 
    28, 37, 37, 15.5, 40.5, 27.5, 30, 37, 51, 11.5, 38.5, 27, 
    24, 20, 23, 8.5, 25, 25.5, 22.5, 13.5, 28, 28, 28.5, 55, 
    51.5, 58, 56, 63, 46, 9, 15, 14.5, 19, 16.5, 8.5, 8.5, 15.5, 
    10, 34.5, 49, 38, 31, 38.5, 46.5, 27.5, 49, 61, 38.5, 37, 
    33, 39, 46, 31.5, 20, 23, 15.5, 23, 39.5, 31.5, 38.5, 61, 
    57, 59, 59, 40.5, 39.5, 56, 34, 11, 6, 7.5), Mean2.5 = c(6.51041675, 
    9.65833325, 14.12291675, 21.475, 19.07708325, 18.1125, 11.975, 
    7.06394925, 9.631069, 16.725, 16.3683875, 8.725, 6.29166675, 
    5.225, 6.15833325, 5.19855066666667, 7.7458335, 7.4083335, 
    7.3166665, 7.51554666666667, 11.8617753333333, 6.32708325, 
    1.60681825, 1.41875, 11.6229165, 7.48541675, 6.475, 11.17916675, 
    10.8833335, 6.96944466666667, 12.2041665, 11.3375, 8, 35.222222, 
    19.5324076666667, 10.20416675, 2.82028975, 15.56666675, 9.29166675, 
    6.9808875, 6.2708335, 8.71684775, 5.37291675, 8.21458325, 
    9.37291675, 6.40833325, 1.8729165, 2.725, 6.975, 11.5208335, 
    8.9291665, 3.4291665, 6.5666665, 3.65833325, 6.23541675, 
    6.3625, 11.16875, 10.7708335, 9.6791665, 9.32708325, 7.42916675, 
    5.1369565, 6.31666675, 5.1895835, 5.3375, 2.77083325, 2.27083325, 
    3.9854165, 3.7458335, 6.68958325, 5.67916675, 4.064855, 5.3625, 
    4.05555566666667, 2.71944466666667, 5.475, 8.0770835, 6.8833335, 
    7.54166675, 10.28125, 6.725, 8.53260875, 9.3625, 6.21458325, 
    7.78125, 6.9214675, 7.06666675, 6.45416675, 5.82708325, 4.71458325, 
    3.78125, 4.35208325, 4.15833325, 4.88333325, 3.68958325, 
    2.0875, 0.89791675, 1.5, 1.671591, 3.91875, 5.06666675, 3.95416675, 
    1.88333325, 3.8729165, 3.225, 2.6333335, 2.1369565, 1.32708325, 
    1.2604165, 1.70869575, 2.4395835, 3.43958325, 5.93958325, 
    5.89375, 5.66875, 4.80625, 3.62291675, 3.76041675, 2.06666675, 
    3.1791665, 4.16875, 3.7604165, 3.5770835, 3.37291675, 4.1333335, 
    4.7617755, 3.31666675, 2.95416675, 2.91875, 2.1882245, 2.965942, 
    3.73541675, 4.3729165, 5.46458325, 5.3375, 3.41875, 3.8729165, 
    4.367029, 2.7708335, 4.93958325, 4.2145835, 5.475, 4.3214015, 
    5.1791665, 3.39375, 3.82708325, 4.41875, 7.53487325, 7.7916665, 
    9.2007575, 7.0666665, 4.7413045, 5.16875, 4.7145835, 5.56666675, 
    5.776515, 6.49722233333333, 4.87916675, 4.87291675, 5.78125, 
    7.41875, 7.28125, 9.43958325, 17.013587, 22.151087, 16.2086955, 
    16.81666675, 14.92418475, 12.6791665, 11.81666675, 9.52083325, 
    10.63662275, 11.2075396666667, 10.04166675, 8.16875, 7.8166665, 
    6.12291675, 6.46458325, 6.28125, 4.26190475, 6.01934525, 
    11.667803, 7.76988625, 8.56458325, 7.1125, 4.77083325, 4.53125, 
    4.65833325, 3.12291675, 3.608114, 3.02490925, 3.01875, 2.34047625, 
    1.59188033333333, 2.6125, 2.08531766666667, 2.46458325, 3.57708325, 
    3.555344, 7.054762, 9.28125, 4.41875, 4.6229165, 5.91875, 
    2.62291675, 2.92237325, 3.65833325, 4.41875, 3.98541675, 
    4.32708325, 5.1583335, 7.63333325, 7.66944433333333, 7.723512, 
    5.98125, 4.476894, 9.33402775, 7.338735, 6.06666675, 1.9607955, 
    2.60208325, 2.18541675, 3.91875, 5.4645835, 6.26041675, 5.90833325, 
    4.16875, 4.28125, 2.13333325, 3.48043475, 4.23541675, 3.9645835, 
    1.064855, 2.6157895, 4.06666675, 4.68958325, 2.36547625, 
    3.23322375, 2.46458325, 1.4958335, 1.57708325, 2.53125, 3.82708325, 
    4.3729165, 2.41875, 3.89375, 6.1092105, 5.80208325, 4.7703805, 
    3.48257575, 3.5625, 4.60555566666667, 2.52777766666667, 2.6125, 
    2.03518325, 5.17767875, 2.3729165, 2.1377195, 2.07219675, 
    4.44682975, 5.52083325, 6.3729165, 2.41875, 2.83055566666667, 
    3.28333333333333, 3.475, 1.23541675, 0.5, 3.12291675, 1.51041675, 
    2.5203805, 7.07708325, 3.67916675, 2.46458325, 2.82708325, 
    2.810779, 3.5770835, 4.01041675, 6.56666675, 4.56666675, 
    5.3375, 4.66875, 4.85931366666667, 6.5666665, 4.45416675, 
    5.225, 4.7839675, 2.71458325, 4.05625, 4.87440475, 8.786111, 
    8.89116166666667, 8.88333325, 8.8375, 3.67916675, 9.725, 
    6.57708325, 7.29166675, 8.9291665, 12.65833325, 2.8833335, 
    9.90833325, 9.09444466666667, 6.89722233333333, 5.322222, 
    5, 2.12563425, 6.03125, 6.225, 5.40833325, 3.17916675, 6.7789855, 
    6.78125, 6.85416675, 12.9381313333333, 13.7708335, 15.32613625, 
    14.417844, 17.9395835, 11.53125, 2.20416675, 3.55625, 3.5208335, 
    4.5416665, 3.975, 2.0666665, 2.1125, 3.67916675, 2.51041675, 
    8.35208325, 11.77083325, 9.0770835, 7.475, 9.27083325, 11.32708325, 
    6.57708325, 11.975, 16.8375, 9.78125, 8.90833325, 7.8729165, 
    9.4854165, 11.16875, 7.55625, 4.82708325, 5.475, 3.71458325, 
    5.6229165, 9.43958325, 7.53125, 9.3270835, 17.62291675, 15.03125, 
    15.92282625, 16.05760875, 10.4395835, 9.475, 14.3625, 8.16875, 
    2.725, 1.29583325, 1.78508775), AQI_10 = c(7, 11.5, 15, 25, 
    24, 22.5, 17, 18.5, 18.5, 17.5, 16.5, 9, 6.5, 6, 6.5, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 17.5, 8.5, 2.5, 4, 15, 10, 8.5, 13.5, 15, 
    11.5, 16.5, 17.5, 19, 25, 23, 45.5, 56.5, 49.5, 27.5, 20, 
    12, 19, 9, 12, 11.5, 8.5, 4, 4.5, 16, 21, 23.5, 6, 7, 4, 
    10, 23.5, 59.5, 59, 45, 13.5, 26.5, 17, 7.5, 9, 9, 7, 25.5, 
    35.5, 38.5, 45, 34.5, 25, 24, 23, 30, 29, 48, 47, 53, 47, 
    32, 44.5, 54.5, 43, 50.5, 44.5, 46, 29, 41.5, 36, 30.5, 30, 
    35, 24.5, 9, 23, 8, 7.5, 19, 24.5, 23, 14, 19, 32.5, 26, 
    10.5, 11, 10.5, 8.5, 4.5, 6.5, 18.5, 34, 32, 23, 19, 14.5, 
    13.5, 9, 14, 15.5, 13.5, 9, 16, 19, 26, 14.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 
    9.5, 11, 16, 20.5, 19, 8.5, 10.5, 11, 11, 17.5, 15, 16.5, 
    9.5, 8, 6.5, 9.5, 11.5, 17, NA, NA, 9, 12.6666666666667, 
    12.6666666666667, 9.66666666666667, 9.66666666666667, 9.33333333333333, 
    18, 10.6666666666667, 11.3333333333333, 12.3333333333333, 
    15, 13.3333333333333, 17.6666666666667, 33, 42, 32, 33.3333333333333, 
    28, 19, 16.3333333333333, 16.6666666666667, 21.6666666666667, 
    20.6666666666667, 24.6666666666667, 14, 11.3333333333333, 
    10, 15.3333333333333, 13.6666666666667, 10.6666666666667, 
    13.6666666666667, 15, 11, 13, 17.3333333333333, 10, 6, 11.3333333333333, 
    10.6666666666667, 11.5, 7.66666666666667, 10.5, 9, 9.33333333333333, 
    10, 7.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 8, 13, 19, 19.3333333333333, 
    9.33333333333333, 13.6666666666667, 11.3333333333333, 4, 
    9, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 12, 12.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 
    16.3333333333333, 19.3333333333333, 15, 13.3333333333333, 
    19, 12.3333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 7.5, 7, 8.66666666666667, 
    13, 13.3333333333333, 10, 6.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
    8.33333333333333, 10, 11.3333333333333, 15, 15, 6.33333333333333, 
    11.3333333333333, 17, 10.3333333333333, 22, 8.66666666666667, 
    6.66666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 10.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 
    22, 10.3333333333333, 7, 7, 10, 7.66666666666667, 7.66666666666667, 
    8, 9.33333333333333, 11.5, 4.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 
    5, 6, 5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 
    10.3333333333333, 10.3333333333333, 13.6666666666667, 9, 
    15.5, 13, 20, 3.5, 2.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 4.5, 
    12.5, 22.3333333333333, 6.66666666666667, 5, 4, 4.5, 9.66666666666667, 
    6.33333333333333, 18, 19.6666666666667, 14, 8.33333333333333, 
    16.6666666666667, 12.6666666666667, 6.33333333333333, 9.66666666666667, 
    5.66666666666667, 4, 3.66666666666667, 10.5, 13.5, 23.5, 
    43.3333333333333, 32.6666666666667, 15.3333333333333, 17, 
    19.6666666666667, 29.6666666666667, 41.3333333333333, 38.6666666666667, 
    9, 39.3333333333333, 25, 6, 6, 15, 10.6666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 
    39, 18, 6.66666666666667, 7.66666666666667, 10, 29, 33, 23.3333333333333, 
    21.6666666666667, 21.3333333333333, 26.3333333333333, 14.3333333333333, 
    7, 5.33333333333333, 6, 5.5, 4.5, 4.66666666666667, 5, 3.66666666666667, 
    3.66666666666667, 10.3333333333333, 16.6666666666667, 25, 
    46, 22.3333333333333, 28.3333333333333, 8, 11.6666666666667, 
    19.6666666666667, 10, 11.6666666666667, 12, 13.6666666666667, 
    15.6666666666667, 7.66666666666667, 7, 6.66666666666667, 
    7, 8, 16, 14.6666666666667, 12, 20.6666666666667, 18, 21, 
    17.3333333333333, 9.33333333333333, 11.6666666666667, 17.3333333333333, 
    6.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 12.5
    ), Mean10 = c(7.5, 12.5, 16, 27, 26, 24.5, 18, 20, 20, 19, 
    17.5, 10, 7.5, 6.5, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18.5, 9.5, 2.5, 
    4, 16, 11, 9.5, 14.5, 16, 12.5, 17.5, 19, 21, 27, 25, 51.5, 
    69.5, 54, 29.5, 21.5, 13, 20.5, 9.5, 13, 12.5, 9.5, 4, 5, 
    17, 22.5, 25.5, 6.5, 8, 4, 11, 25, 72, 72, 48.5, 14.5, 28.5, 
    18, 8.5, 10, 10, 8, 27.5, 39.5, 42, 49, 37, 27, 26, 25, 32.5, 
    31, 52.5, 52.5, 59.5, 51, 34.5, 48.5, 63, 46.5, 56, 48.5, 
    49.5, 31, 44.5, 39, 33, 32.5, 38, 26.5, 10, 25, 8.5, 8, 21, 
    26, 25, 15, 20.5, 35, 28, 11.5, 12, 11.5, 9, 4.5, 7.5, 20, 
    36.5, 34.5, 24.5, 20.5, 15.5, 14.5, 10, 15, 16.5, 14.5, 10, 
    17, 20.5, 28, 15.5, 8.5, 8, 8.5, 10.5, 12, 17, 22.5, 21, 
    9.5, 11.5, 12, 12, 18.5, 16, 17.5, 10.5, 9, 7, 10.5, 12.5, 
    18, NA, NA, 10, 14, 14, 10.3333333333333, 10.3333333333333, 
    10.3333333333333, 19.5, 11.6666666666667, 12.3333333333333, 
    13.6666666666667, 16.3333333333333, 14.3333333333333, 19, 
    35.3333333333333, 46, 34.3333333333333, 35.6666666666667, 
    30.3333333333333, 20.3333333333333, 17.6666666666667, 17.6666666666667, 
    23.3333333333333, 22.6666666666667, 27, 15, 12.3333333333333, 
    11, 16.6666666666667, 14.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 
    14.6666666666667, 16, 12, 14, 18.6666666666667, 11, 6.5, 
    12.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 12.5, 8.33333333333333, 
    11.5, 10, 10, 11, 8, 7, 9, 14, 20.3333333333333, 20.6666666666667, 
    10.3333333333333, 15, 12.3333333333333, 4.5, 9.66666666666667, 
    11, 11.5, 11.5, 13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 14.3333333333333, 
    17.6666666666667, 20.6666666666667, 16.3333333333333, 14.3333333333333, 
    20.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 7.33333333333333, 8, 
    7.66666666666667, 9.33333333333333, 14, 14.3333333333333, 
    11, 7, 5.33333333333333, 9, 11, 12.3333333333333, 16.3333333333333, 
    16.3333333333333, 6.66666666666667, 12.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 
    11.3333333333333, 24, 9.66666666666667, 7, 8.33333333333333, 
    11.3333333333333, 14.6666666666667, 24, 11.3333333333333, 
    7.5, 7.33333333333333, 11, 8.33333333333333, 8.66666666666667, 
    8.66666666666667, 10.3333333333333, 12.5, 4.33333333333333, 
    5, 5.33333333333333, 6.5, 5.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 
    6.66666666666667, 11.3333333333333, 11, 15, 9.66666666666667, 
    17, 14.5, 21.6666666666667, 3.5, 2.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 
    4.5, 13.5, 23.6666666666667, 7, 5, 4, 5, 10.3333333333333, 
    7, 19.3333333333333, 21, 15.3333333333333, 9.33333333333333, 
    18, 14, 7, 10.6666666666667, 6, 4, 3.66666666666667, 11.5, 
    14.5, 25.5, 52.3333333333333, 35.3333333333333, 16.6666666666667, 
    18.3333333333333, 21, 32, 45.3333333333333, 42, 9.66666666666667, 
    44, 27, 6.66666666666667, 6.33333333333333, 16.3333333333333, 
    11.6666666666667, 7.33333333333333, 43.5, 19.3333333333333, 
    7, 8.33333333333333, 11, 33.6666666666667, 39, 25.3333333333333, 
    23.3333333333333, 23, 28.3333333333333, 15.6666666666667, 
    7.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6, 
    4.5, 5, 5.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 4, 11.3333333333333, 
    18, 27, 51.3333333333333, 24, 30.6666666666667, 9, 12.6666666666667, 
    21.3333333333333, 11, 12.6666666666667, 13, 14.6666666666667, 
    16.6666666666667, 8.66666666666667, 7.66666666666667, 7, 
    7.66666666666667, 8.33333333333333, 17, 16, 13, 22, 19.3333333333333, 
    23, 18.3333333333333, 10, 12.6666666666667, 18.6666666666667, 
    7, 4.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 14)), row.names = c(1L, 
37L, 77L, 133L, 168L, 205L, 265L, 300L, 337L, 390L, 422L, 458L, 
516L, 549L, 589L, 646L, 681L, 720L, 781L, 816L, 854L, 912L, 947L, 
986L, 1047L, 1083L, 1121L, 1178L, 1214L, 1253L, 1314L, 1349L, 
1386L, 1443L, 1478L, 1516L, 1577L, 1611L, 1650L, 1706L, 1740L, 
1778L, 1840L, 1876L, 1915L, 1968L, 2001L, 2037L, 2094L, 2128L, 
2164L, 2215L, 2250L, 2288L, 2350L, 2385L, 2424L, 2479L, 2512L, 
2550L, 2614L, 2648L, 2686L, 2742L, 2775L, 2813L, 2874L, 2909L, 
2947L, 3004L, 3040L, 3079L, 3142L, 3178L, 3217L, 3275L, 3311L, 
3350L, 3414L, 3449L, 3488L, 3547L, 3583L, 3622L, 3686L, 3722L, 
3760L, 3815L, 3850L, 3888L, 3951L, 3986L, 4024L, 4081L, 4115L, 
4153L, 4216L, 4250L, 4288L, 4346L, 4381L, 4419L, 4481L, 4516L, 
4553L, 4609L, 4643L, 4682L, 4742L, 4776L, 4814L, 4872L, 4907L, 
4944L, 5006L, 5040L, 5077L, 5133L, 5167L, 5203L, 5266L, 5300L, 
5338L, 5394L, 5429L, 5466L, 5529L, 5564L, 5601L, 5655L, 5690L, 
5729L, 5791L, 5828L, 5867L, 5924L, 5959L, 5997L, 6058L, 6096L, 
6136L, 6195L, 6231L, 6270L, 6330L, 6368L, 6407L, 6462L, 6499L, 
6633L, 6672L, 6726L, 6763L, 6800L, 6863L, 6901L, 6939L, 6996L, 
7031L, 7069L, 7132L, 7167L, 7206L, 7265L, 7302L, 7340L, 7404L, 
7439L, 7476L, 7534L, 7570L, 7607L, 7671L, 7706L, 7743L, 7802L, 
7837L, 7874L, 7938L, 7972L, 8009L, 8067L, 8102L, 8140L, 8204L, 
8240L, 8278L, 8337L, 8373L, 8411L, 8471L, 8506L, 8542L, 8600L, 
8635L, 8671L, 8734L, 8768L, 8805L, 8862L, 8898L, 8936L, 9000L, 
9036L, 9074L, 9129L, 9163L, 9199L, 9261L, 9296L, 9333L, 9389L, 
9424L, 9461L, 9523L, 9559L, 9596L, 9650L, 9685L, 9722L, 9782L, 
9817L, 9855L, 9913L, 9947L, 9984L, 10047L, 10082L, 10119L, 10176L, 
10210L, 10245L, 10308L, 10344L, 10381L, 10439L, 10476L, 10513L, 
10576L, 10608L, 10643L, 10698L, 10735L, 10772L, 10834L, 10868L, 
10905L, 10961L, 10997L, 11034L, 11095L, 11130L, 11169L, 11226L, 
11262L, 11298L, 11361L, 11396L, 11433L, 11489L, 11522L, 11558L, 
11622L, 11658L, 11694L, 11749L, 11785L, 11822L, 11884L, 11922L, 
11959L, 12014L, 12051L, 12088L, 12146L, 12179L, 12214L, 12270L, 
12305L, 12341L, 12402L, 12437L, 12474L, 12531L, 12565L, 12600L, 
12662L, 12696L, 12732L, 12787L, 12819L, 12854L, 12912L, 12946L, 
12981L, 13035L, 13068L, 13103L, 13165L, 13201L, 13238L, 13293L, 
13327L, 13362L, 13423L, 13456L, 13490L, 13547L, 13579L, 13613L, 
13672L, 13705L, 13740L, 13798L, 13831L, 13866L, 13925L, 13958L, 
13992L, 14047L, 14080L, 14115L, 14173L, 14205L, 14239L, 14295L, 
14329L, 14364L, 14423L, 14455L, 14490L, 14546L, 14579L, 14615L, 
14677L, 14712L, 14748L, 14805L, 14840L, 14877L, 14938L, 14974L, 
15012L, 15067L, 15100L, 15136L, 15199L, 15234L, 15271L, 15329L, 
15363L, 15400L, 15462L, 15498L, 15535L, 15592L, 15627L, 15665L, 
15727L, 15763L, 15800L, 15857L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: that is a lot of data ... have you tried checking with `unique()` if the data you are trying to join on differs (slightly)

Comment: Trim your data, (; e.g. counties in file2 contain spaces at the end and will therefore not match, i.e. "Anchorage" != "Anchorage ".

Comment: WOW! unbelievable! Thank you so much! @stefan for reference, to check this next time, what's a quick command in R?

Comment: I saw it when using dplyr's full_join instead of merge. But you can see it also by comparing as.character(file2$County) vs. as.character(file1$County) or  levels(file1$County) vs. levels(file2$County) or having a look at the datasets with str().